# Count Checkboxes with Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm making a form that is for a summer camp registration form where users will be registering. By the end of the form there is an option of paying in full or making a $50 deposit for each camp selected. I'm using hidden products to handle the total amount per week and adding their value into the total. My question comes if I can use formulas to count the number of checkboxes that have been selected and do the calculations.

Example:

Week 1:

- Soccer camp

Week 2:

- Computer camp

Total: $100 (Deposit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually have a snippet for this:

<strike>https://gist.github.com/spivurno/077fd21a993e9b573d46</strike>

Updated: https://gist.github.com/spivurno/a14ef4a18f57d0c67811e1b4d8791781

The parameters are:

- `form_id` the ID of the form for which you would like to count the checkboxes
- `count_field_id` the ID of the field into which you would like to populate the checkbox count (you can then use this field's merge tag in a Calculation formula)
- `checkbox_field_ids` an array of Checkbox field IDs whose checkboxes should count towards the checkbox count (when checked)

Comment: That's pretty cool! Thanks. I'm new to WordPress though. How would you install this snippet? Thanks again.

Comment: You can install this via the [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin or by copying and pasting the code in your theme's *functions.php* file. More instructions here: http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/snippet-troubleshooting/

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate it.

Comment: I was wondering if you knew how to make the number field as a payment total. I appreciate any help. Best.