# In a calculation field in Gravity Forms, how do I get the number of checkboxes selected in a checkbox field?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a checkbox field that allows a user to select a number of weeks to register for, *e.g.*

> **Weeks**
>
> - June 6 - June 10
> - June 13 - June 17
> - June 20 - June 24
> - June 27 - July 1

Now, I want to have an option,

> **Add Extended Care option for $75 per week?**
>
> - No
> - Yes

so that if selected, a calculation field becomes 75 times the number of weeks selected.

I think I'm missing something obvious, because the only way this seems possible to me, is by assigning each week a value of "1" and writing a formula that sums all the week values. But then, this makes it impossible to distinguish from the form entries what weeks were selected. To get around this, I've thought of assigning each week an increasing value 1, 2, 3... and dividing each week's value by itself, *e.g.* {{Week 1}}/{{Week 1}}, to always yield 1 in the formula, while preserving unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to count checkboxes:

[Count Checkboxes with Gravity Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956751/count-checkboxes-with-gravity-forms/34970021#34970021)

Happy to answer any questions.

Comment: I found that answer early today and already installed your snippet :-) I was going to mark this question closed as duplicate. Thank you for your work!

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found it useful. :)

Comment: Hey, David. Is your snippet supposed to update the number `onclick` or `onchange`? Or, does it only do a final update on form submission? One thing I already had to modify was change `#input` to `#choice`, as their id's seem to have changed.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything outside of the Configuration section. Here's an example of it working on my end: http://gravitywiz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/gw-checkbox-counter.gif

Comment: Er... my checkboxes have id's like `choice_1_4_1`, `choice_1_4_2`, where the numbers are form id, field id, and option. Things have definitely changed... but I see that things update dynamically in your video, so I'll try to fix the code to work for my case.

Comment: That video is based on the latest version of Gravity Forms. The config doesn't require that you touch any of the HTML IDs. Only the field IDs. This does not target specific checkboxes but all checkboxes of the specified field.

Comment: Ah, you were absolutely right. I walked in with the wrong assumption that all eligible checkboxes would be listed explicitly, and started looking at the individual checkbox id's. Works perfectly. Thanks again!